# Getting cufon to work in IE7 & IE8 - I've done everything according to doc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For the life of me, I can't figure out why Cufon isn't working for me in IE7 & 8 (it probably doesn't with IE6 or lower either, but I'm not concerned about that).

So far I've tried:

- Adding the function `Cufon.now();`.
- Placing `$(document).ready( function() {});` around my `Cufon.replace();` function.
- Re-generating the `font-name.js` file with the official Cufon website.
- Isolating the text I want replaced and relevant CSS/JS into a separate file to see if it makes a difference.
- Adding the `font-family: [NAME]` self assigned in the Cufon font generator to the `font-family:` property of the element I want replaced.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why it's not working.

Here's a link to my isolated script on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xzv2X/1/

Does anyone know of any other common errors that could possibly be the issue here?

Just a note, I'm using Adobe Browser Labs as my IE7 & IE8 previewer.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated :) :) :), as this is really starting to get to me, as I've read at least 5 different webpages (including Cufon's own GitHub FAQ) that says it's compatible with IE5+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

1. Removing `type="application/javascript"`
2. Not nesting `head` inside of `<body>`

Comment: How is it nested? Do you mean that jsFiddle automatically nests everything in the HTML box inside of `<body>`? + Thanks for your help, I'll try that now :).

Comment: Yes.. If you view the source of the frame you'll see.

Comment: Removing `type="application/javascript" worked brilliantly!`, thanks a million! I take it IE messes up when you declare the script type as `application/javascript` or something?