# dropdown menu items are hidden in ie8

Tags: css, superfish, skeleton-css-boilerplate

In IE8 Document mode IE8 I am using the wp-skeleton theme by [simplethemes](http://themes.simplethemes.com/skeleton/) which uses a variation of superfish. All appears to work well across browsers except for IE8 which appears like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to recode some css for IE8, 
besides I don think it's an important matter about IE8, Let the guys have an update of software ;)

Comment: Can you tell me which elements need to be recoded for the IE8 exceptions? I would have done this already if I knew which css attributes and elements were causing the problems.

Comment: let me see ;) I'm now using IE 10 , Chrome 24, firefox 19, opera 12.12,and safari 5.1.7. but got no IE 8 , but gimme some minute so i can see how to tell you which ones to edit / recode ;)

Comment: does the menu works now under IE 8 , regardless the text are not shown, does the shortcuts work ? 
If the menu still works but the text is not shown, it's becuz of the HTML5 tag, cufon, used which do not work in IE < 8 . I'll look for a solution and tell you soon

Comment: here is a link about coufon usage in IE8 and 7 [THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041781/getting-cufon-to-work-in-ie7-ie8-ive-done-everything-according-to-doc)

you can also read the folowing page for a complete guide on how to embed coufon, [THIS 2nd LINK](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Usage)

 you actually need to edit your wp-theme for more compatibility with previous browsers ;)

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't like overflow:hidden, so you could try removing it. Another thread mentions is located in ie.css: #header_container #nav_container.

Comment: Where do you see `overflow : hidden` can you point me in the right direction? Also, I do not see an ie.css file https://github.com/simplethemes/skeleton_wp/tree/master/skeleton